# Step by Step to install postfix using putty

Tags: php, email, putty, postfix

I have problem with my php mail(). I have check smtp server is enabled. php.ini is as follows:

```
[mail function]

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =
```

So I read some offline document saying to use postfix to solve it.
But I am new to Postfix. I have putty. I tried http://www.servermom.com/easy-way-to-install-postfix-on-ubuntu-server/197/ but I have problem even at step 1 (apt-get error).
Please help me..

Comment: Have you managed to successfully login to your server first via the putty ssh client? If you have, and you are getting errors from apt-get, try prefixing the command with sudo apt-get... Report back with the exact steps or commands that you tried.

Comment: Hi. I tried sudo. I get this error:
sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: Ok, so I guess sudo isn't installed by default in your system. You are running as root though I hope? What is the initial error you got from apt-get that you mentioned in your problem description? Can you take a screenshot and upload it on http://imgur.com/ ?